# extracting key from given array with "value"

Tags: php, arrays

we have an array which looks something like this

```
<?php
    $list = array(
        'liquid'=>array('water','soft drink'),
        'solid'=>array('car','computer','floor'),
        'gas'=>array('air','oxygen','carbon dioxide'),
    );
?>
```

now this is just an example list, what we are trying to achieve is

a user passes a value in a function like this

```
<?php
    function return_state($matter_value){
        return array_search($matter_value, $list);
    }
?>
```

- user passes `water` the result should be **liquid**
- user passes `floor` the result should be **solid**

> in short whatever user is passing it will return the **key** associated with it

but when we are executing this function, it returns ''(empty value).

What are we doing wrong ?

Comment: You should also get an error telling you that $list doesn't exist, because it is out of scope for your function, so you need to pass it to the function as an argument

Comment: Then use a foreach loop to iterate over each top-level array value, and do your array_search, returning only if a match is found

Comment: @runningmark, You need to check answers [Frayne Konok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248607/extracting-key-from-given-array-with-value/37248736#37248736)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a `foreach` loop with `in_array` makes this easy.

```
$list = array(
        'liquid'=>array('water','soft drink'),
        'solid'=>array('car','computer','floor'),
        'gas'=>array('air','oxygen','carbon dioxide'),
    );
function return_state($matter_value, $list){    
    foreach($list as $key => $val){
        if(in_array($matter_value, $val))
            return $key;        
    }
    return 'Not found.';
}

echo return_state('floor', $list); //solid
```

> Pass your array through the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` loop and `in_array` function:

```
function return_state($matter_value = ""){
    $list = [
        'liquid' => ['water','soft drink'],
        'solid' => ['car','computer','floor'],
        'gas' => ['air','oxygen','carbon dioxide'],
    ];
    if (!empty($matter_value)) {   // avoids empty arguments
        foreach ($list as $key => $items) {
            if (in_array($matter_value, $items)) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

print_r(return_state("water"));   // "liquid"
print_r(return_state("floor"));   // "solid"
```

Comment: `trim` returns the trimmed string. You should assign it to the `matter_value` variable, otherwise the function call is useless. after assigning it you can use the `empty` function to make sure the string is not empty

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` not able to find in inner arrays. It will look into main array i.e. liquid, solid, gas and its values (not an array). You need loop through keys of main array to search key.

```
<?php
    function return_state($matter_value,$list){
        foreach($list as $key=>$item){
            $test=array_search($matter_value, $item);
            if($test!==FALSE){
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution to the problem. It makes the matter_value an array and intersects it with every element of the $list array. If nothing matched, the result will be *null*.

```
function return_state($matter_value, $list) {
    foreach ($list as $list_item_key => $list_item) {
        if ( ! empty(array_intersect([$matter_value], array_values($list_item)))) {
            return $list_item_key;
        }
    }
}
```